# What should I select for the option on the OpenGL dialogue box regarding Cairo Dock on ASUS laptop w / Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2830 @ 2.16GHz × 2

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel-graphics, opengl, cairo-dock

I'm a new Ubuntu user. I just installed Ubuntu, and it was utterly screwed up at first (wouldn't display text reliably anywhere). I'm using it to learn to program, and I don't want to spend hours every day fidgeting around with the core of the OS. I've been using a stable configuration that allows me to learn programming for weeks, and have simply refused updates that might break this stable configuration. However, it just froze and had to be restarted.

Cairo Dock had been stable, and I had been using it. Now, on startup I have a dialogue box that asks which of two settings I want, without letting me know which one I had been using. I, as a human being, should NEVER be asked which option I want without the computer figuring out which hardware is relevant, and which hardware I possess on my computer. The dialogue box asks the following: "OpenGL allows you to use hardware acceleration, reducing CPU load to a minimum. It also allows some pretty visual effects similar to Compiz. However, some cards and/or their drivers do not fully support it, which may prevent the dock from running correctly. Do you want to activate OpenGL? (To not show this dialogue, launch the dock from the Applications menu, or with the -o flag to force OpenGL or -c to force cairo.) [yes][no]

I WANT NOTHING THAT ISN'T TOTALLY STABLE ON MY MACHINE.

With this in mind, does anyone else see the problem with this idiotic dialogue box that asks questions without providing me with the relevant information I need to make a decision? This is the problem with GNU+Linux. I don't want to have to be a technical expert in graphics cards just to start up the computer, check my email, and continue doing the project I was working on prior to the crash. For weeks I had no idea if I was using OpenGL or not, and everything worked fine.

Here is the dialogue box again, this time with my <> indicating the kind of information I'd need to have to make "the right decision, for my situation" and asking where to find it, since I don't have it.

"OpenGL allows you to use hardware acceleration, reducing CPU load to a minimum. <> It also allows some pretty visual effects similar to Compiz.<> However, some cards and/or their drivers do not fully support it<>, which may prevent the dock from running correctly. Do you want to activate OpenGL? <> (To not show this dialogue, launch the dock from the Applications menu, or with the -o flag to force OpenGL or -c to force cairo.) [yes][no] <>

I'm running:
Memory: 3.8 GiB
Processor: Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2830 @ 2.16GHz × 2
Graphics: Intel® Bay Trail 
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 488.0 GB

Answer (score 0):

Quotes from Cairo-Dock Official Forum.

> OpenGL use GPU, whereas Cairo use CPU. So, if your graphical card have
>   a good support ( for example a lot of Nvidia)

In your case i would suggest you to choose openGL option. Since your processor (sorry) was suck....

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that I should NOT choose the openGL option? 

Your answer is confusing to me. I have an Intel graphics card that came with the laptop, as I noted above, it's "Graphics: Intel® Bay Trail"

Comment: nope, you better choose the openGL option